# Regex for OCR Clean-up

Tags: python, regex

I have been digitizing some books and hope to clean up the table of contents. My output looks something like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit.
(January 1, 2008)
Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem 
ipsum quia dolor
(June 30, 2007)361
Finibus Bonorum et Malorum
(July 3, 2008)398
```

I want to separate individual articles using `\)\d*\n*`, but how do I match up to this string?

Some page numbers are missing, and some titles, such as `Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor`, have been printed on multiple lines.

Ideally, I want to divide them into something like `Finibus Bonorum et Malorum (July 3, 2008)398` to extract title, date, and page number.

Sorry for asking such an elementary question! Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex to extract the different parts:

```
(.*?)(?=\([^\)]*\)\d*(?:\n|$))\(([^)]*)\)(\d*)(?:\n|$)
```

It has 3 capture groups:

1. All the text up to the first `(` that is followed by only one `)`, optional digits and end of line or string (this is so it will work with titles which have `(` in them;
2. The text between `(` and `)`;
3. Any digits after the `)` and up to a newline or end of string.

Example usage:

```
import re

txt = '''Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur 
adipiscing elit.
(January 1, 2008)
The 39
steps
(June 30, 2007)361
A title with
a (bracketed) word
(April 1, 2020)34
Finibus Bonorum et Malorum
(July 3, 2008)398'''
pattern = re.compile(r'(.*?)(?=\([^\)]*\)\d*(?:\n|$))\(([^)]*)\)(\d*)(?:\n|$)', re.S)
print(pattern.findall(txt))
```

Output:

```
[
 ('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur \nadipiscing elit.\n', 'January 1, 2008', ''),
 ('The 39\nsteps\n', 'June 30, 2007', '361'),
 ('A title with\na (bracketed) word\n', 'April 1, 2020', '34'),
 ('Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\n', 'July 3, 2008', '398')
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning up text is hard work. The provided samples can be combined in one like using a regex-replace like this

```
([\w ,]+)\n(?:([\w ,.]+)\n)?(\(\w+ \d+, \d+\)\d*)
```

Code Sample

```
import re
regex = r"([\w ,]+)\n(?:([\w ,.]+)\n)?(\(\w+ \d+, \d+\)\d*)"
subst = "$1$2 $3"
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)
```

[Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/HnCfWb/1)